# Issue with upgrading Magento 2 from 2.3.5-p2 to 2.3.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch, magento-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2 with the latest release **Magento 2.3.6** and getting an error while running the **upgrade command**.

**Unable to apply data patch Magento\Elasticsearch\Setup\Patch\Data\InvalidateIndex for module Magento_Elasticsearch. Original exception message: Notice: Undefined index:  in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config.php on line 93**

Currently we are using Magento 2.3.5-p2 version and algolia for search.
Previously we used Wyomind Elastic search and now the modules are disabled.

Do anyone have an idea about the issue? Please help me to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename `vendor` folder to `vendor-old` and run `composer update` if it's correctly configured.

When renamed `vendor` folder follow steps below:

1. Make a backup copy of composer.json in your Magento installation directory
2. Open composer.json in a text editor.
3. Locate the following line:

> "require": {
> "magento/product-community-edition": ""
> },

4. Replace  with the version to which you want to upgrade, where  is the product version to use, in your case 2.3.6.
5. Save your changes and run the following command:
   `composer update`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/dev_reinstall.html